# Preventing unmanaged function pointer garbage collection

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, garbage-collection, clr

The documentation for converting delegates to unmanaged code states that I am responsible for preventing it's collection myself. I wish to know if the delegate cannot be collected whilst the unmanaged call is live. For example, if I do

```
UnmanagedFunction(arg => somebody);
```

where UnmanagedFunction does not store the function pointer beyond it's invocation. This should be legal, right? The CLR can't collect whilst the UnmanagedFunction is executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [CLR Inside Out: Marshaling between Managed and Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx):

> Usually, you won't have to worry about the lifetime of delegates. Whenever you are passing a delegate to unmanaged code, **the CLR will make sure the delegate is alive during the call**.

Seems you're okay.

Since you explicitly mention

> `UnmanagedFunction` does not store the function pointer beyond it's invocation.

the next paragraph in the article

> However, **if the native code keeps a copy of the pointer beyond the span of the call and intends to call back through that pointer later**, you might need to use `GCHandle` to explicitly prevent the garbage collector from collecting the delegate.

does *not* apply.