# How To hook unmanaged function inside managed function?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net

Here is my C++ Code:
This function is exported in my DLL.

```
EXPORT set_hook(fnc_public_hook hook){
    public_hook = hook;
}
```

Now if I hook it from unmanaged code like following everything works fine.

```
set_hook(my_fnc);
```

Now before every event in my DLL `my_fnc` is called, so I can do some pre process on data.

The problem is that I don't know how to do this in .NET.
How to get .NET function pointer ? And how to use `set_hook()` to call my .NET function before every event ?

Comment: Just use `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`. Do mind that you need to keep a reference to the delegate, though, or it's going to get garbage collected.

Comment: @Luaan I guess you misunderstood me. Not only I want to send my .NET function pointer, I want C++ to call my .NET function.

Comment: You misunderstood Luaan, your C++ code *will* call the .NET code as long as you call public_hook().

Comment: Yes - that's what `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` is for. You create a delegate, hold it somewhere (GCHandle works fine) and then call `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` and pass the IntPtr to the `set_hook` method. This will allow the C++ code to call back into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Somewhere, create a delegate to your function you would like called

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal delegate uint YourFunctionDelegate();
```

Set your delegate to point to your function, ie in your constructor,

```
YourFunctionDelegate = myDotNetFunc;
```

In NativeMethods class inside your namespace,

```
[DllImport("YourDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "set_hook", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int setHook([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]YourFunctionDelegate myDelegate);
```

Finally, you can call your c++ function with

```
NativeMethods.setHook(YourFunctionDelegate);
```

Make sure you know which calling convention is appropriate.

EDIT: Dont get garbage collected!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182294%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

[Preventing unmanaged function pointer garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251754/preventing-unmanaged-function-pointer-garbage-collection)

Comment: One thing to beware of is that if you have a model of "I call C with a delegate, before the return, the delegate gets invoked", you're in great shape and your code will be reliable.  If the model is, "I call C with a delegate, it returns and then after much time I call C and then my delegate gets invoked" you are likely to have problems.  In my experience, the CLR will eventually garbage college your delegate and its unmanaged thunk.

Comment: You are correct. I was pulling from a project at work and forgot to mention I was using a SafeHandle.